# Doubt regarding divisibility of the expression: $1^{101}+2^{101} \cdot \cdot \cdot +2016^{101}$

Tags: summation, contest-math, divisibility

In an interesting contest question I recently encountered, I chanced upon a question I couldn't solve.

---

$$\sum^{2016}_{i=1}i^{101}$$ is divisible by: (a)2014 (b)2015 (c)2016 (d)2017

---

How would I go about solving this question in a no-nonsense fashion?

Comment: As answers show, it is divisible by both $2016$ and $2017$. Interestingly enough, it is also divisible by $2017^2$. I don't yet see a clear reason for this, but WA confirms it.

Comment: Even more interesting you noticed that! @alex.jordan :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We prove that $2016$ and $2017$ are divisors but $2014$ and $2015$ are not while minimizing computation.

---

Note the identity

$$m^{2k+1} + n^{2k+1} = (m + n)(m^{2k} - m^{2k-1}n + \dots - mn^{2k-1} + n^{2k})$$

Hence,

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{2016} n^{101} &= (2016^{101} + 1^{101}) + (2015^{101} + 2^{101}) + \dots + (1009^{101} + 1008^{101})\\
&= 2017 N_1 + 2017 N_2 + \dots + 2017 N_{1008}.
\end{align}

so the sum is divisible by $2017$. Using similar logic, we can also show it is divisible by 2016. Indeed,

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{2016} n^{101} &= 2016^{101} + \sum_{n=1}^{2015} n^{101} = 2016^{101} + 2016N + 1008^{101}\\
 &= 2016^{101} + 2016N + 2016\cdot \frac{1008^{101}}{2}\\
\end{align}

so $2016$ is also a divisor.

---

Now we prove that the others do not work.

The sum is "almost" divisible by $2015$, having a remainder of $1$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2015} n^{101}$$

is divisible by $2015$, and $2016^{101} \equiv 1^{101} \equiv 1 \mod 2015$.

To prove that $2014$ doesn't work is harder.

We know $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{2014} n^{101} \equiv 1007^{101} \mod 2014$ since it is unpaired. We have $1007^2 \equiv 1007 (-1007) \equiv -1007^2 \mod 2014$, hence $1007^2 \equiv 1007 \mod 2014$ since $1007$ is the only remainder which is the same when negative or positive. Hence, $1007^n \equiv 1007 \mod 2014$ for any $n$.

The remaining terms are $2015^{101} + 2016^{101}$. $2015^{101} \equiv 1^{101} \equiv 1$.

I'm not entirely convinced there's an intended clean way to prove that $2016^{101}$ is not equivalent to $1006 \mod 2014$. The approach that comes to mind is brute force using

$$2016^{101} = 2^{101} \equiv (2048 = 2^{11})^9 \cdot 2^2 \equiv 34^9 \cdot 2^2$$

Comment: Are you sure that $\sum_{n=1}^{2015}=2016N$?

Comment: The logic for separating a $2016N$ term is _slightly_ different, because $1008^{101}$ has no term to pair up with. However, it is the same as $2016\cdot504\cdot1008^{99}$, so it too is divisible by $2016$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I will update the answer.

Comment: Actually, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{2014} n^{101} \equiv 1007 \mod 2014$ as $1007^{101}$ is not paired up with anything, and it is divisible by $1007$, but not by $2$.

Comment: @Soke I'm talking about divisibility by 2014. In the sum from 1 to 2013, 1007 is not paired with anything, and $1007^{101}$ is not divisible by 2014, so the sum from 1 to 2013 is not divisible by 2014.

Comment: @Litho Oh, gotcha sorry. So the proof isn't as clean as it was now..

Answer (score 5):

On the one hand,
$$
\sum^{2016}_{i=1}i^{101}
=\sum^{1008}_{i=1}i^{101}
+\sum^{1008}_{i=1}(2017-i)^{101}
$$
The two sums cancel mod $2017$ because $101$ is odd.

On the other hand,
$$
\sum^{2016}_{i=1}i^{101}
=\sum^{1007}_{i=1}i^{101}
+\sum^{1007}_{i=1}(2016-i)^{101}
+1008^{101}
$$

The two sums cancel mod $2016$ because $101$ is odd.

Finally, $1008^{101}=\dfrac{2016}{2}\cdot 1008^{100}$ is a multiple of $2016$ because $1008$ is even.

You can apply the same argument for $2014$ and $2015$ and you'll get lots of cancellation but a nonzero remainder.

Comment: Very succinct answer; +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

$$a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}=(a+b)(a^{2k}-\ldots+b^{2k})$$

$1^{101}+2016^{101}=(1+2016) \cdot A_1=2017A_1,$ where $A_1 \in \mathbb Z$

$2^{101}+2015^{101}=(2+2015) \cdot A_2=2017A_2,$ where $A_2 \in \mathbb Z$

...

$i^{101}+(2017-i)^{101}=(i+2017-i) \cdot A_i=2017A_i,$ where $A_i \in \mathbb Z$

...

$1013^{101}+1014^{101}=(1013+1014) \cdot A=2017A_{1013},$ where $A_{1013} \in \mathbb Z$

Then:
$$2017\mid\sum^{2016}_{i=1}i^{101}$$

Answer: 2017

Comment: Nice answer; what's the dotted expression in the first identity you've posted? Could you please explicitly mention?

Comment: What about showing that the other options don't divide the sum? In fact even $2016$ divides the sum by the same logic $(1+2015)A$ and $2016^{101}$ is trivially divisible

Comment: @BanachTarski That's probably a much more difficult question.

Comment: @Soke but without that the answer is incomplete :)

Comment: @BanachTarski Actually, it is also divisible by $2016$, so yea, the answer is incomplete.

Comment: Yes. I was going to comment this after I recently discovered that it doesn't aptly invalidate the other options,but @BanachTarski seems to have brought this up.

And correct: The answers to this question are options (c) and (d).

Comment: Also, since when does (1013+1014)=2017?

Comment: If we club the terms the same way for 2015, we will see that it divides the sum uptill $i = 2015$. Now for $2016^{101}$, we know that 2015 and 2016 are comprime, thus 2015 cannot divide $2016^{101}$ and hence does not divide the sum

Comment: @Kugelblitz Roman83 just selected the wrong intermediate terms for the sum (the correct ones are $1008$ and $1009$. Anyhow, I am currently making an answer that shows each answer as true or not.

Comment: Yea. Noticed. I essentially wanted Roman83 to make the required edit before some cast unwarranted downvotes.